# Laravel collection sortby Illegal string offset 'detail'

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I need sortby detail name "ASC"

I follow this link.https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby

[image]

this my debug data

[image]

This my code

```
$collection = collect($data);
dd($collection);
$sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
    return count($product['detail']);
});

$sorted->values()->all();
```

But show error "Illegal string offset 'detail'"

Answer (score 0):

Next time please post code/dd results as text and not screenshots. Thanks!

Here:

```
$collection = collect($data);
```

your `$data` isn't an array of products, but rather 1 product (presumably an array of product's attributes).

So what happens is the `->sortBy(..)` iterates over the attributes `name` and `detail`.

So in the first iteration (you can see that by doing `dd($product)` within the `sortBy`) the `$product` is actually this:

```
'Tour Guide Multilingual'
```

and the key is:

```
'product'
```

And you get the error because you're trying to access index `['detail']` on a string (thus "Illegal *string* offset 'detail'")

So it's a logic problem. I'm not sure how you get your `$data` or what your expected result is, but you only have 1 product in your `$data` so there's nothing to sort by really

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$collection = collect($data);
$sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
    return $product['name'];
});

$sorted->values()->all();
```

Comment: Use `$product['name']` instead of `$product['detail']`, if you want to sort on basis of name without `count()`

Comment: this dd($product) 
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "detail" => "Speaking Guide - English"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "detail" => "Audio - Thai"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "detail" => "Audio - Chinese"
  ]
]
and this my code 
$collection = collect($data);
        $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
            dd($product);
            return $product['detail'];
        });

Comment: in this case use `return $product[0]['detail'];`

Comment: the result yet same

Comment: can you comment down `dd()` of `$collection` before using sortBy()?